# Should I be afraid of getting too many up votes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

I have had a question in mind for a long time:

Imagine that I posted a good answer to a question. Is it okay for the OP to up-vote all of my posts (answers and questions) without my knowledge? I know that the OP can accept my answer and up-vote it, but is it legitimate for the OP to up-vote *all* of my posts?

For example, if I had 200 questions and 100 answers, the OP up-voting all of my posts would result in a high reputation gain, like 1000 rep at the one time. What should I do about it?

Can I up-vote all of a user´s posts without knowing him? Will I or the OP get banned? Will all of the reputation be taken away?

Comment: Why you should be banned for well received questions?

Comment: @user0042 because they thing, OP is my friend and i ask to up vote all my post!

Comment: That is a bad idea. Serial votes like that will be reversed. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829

Comment: “because they thing, OP is my friend and i ask to up vote all my post! ” - Yes, This behavior is against the rules and grounds for a suspension for abuse of the voting system.  Users can only vote 50 times a day.  So it’s impossible to get 1,000 reputation points from a single user in a single day.  You would both be permanently before that 51st serial upvote by the way.

Comment: @Ramhound Why got -13 down vote!! i'm banned from stack exchange!, just for this question ! :| why!?!

Comment: @user8001250 It is not possible to be question banned from a single question.  You have several questions that were downvoted.   Deleted questions also count against and towards your ability to submit new questions.  Additionally the rate limit on a meta website is extremely high.  You have not been question banned here at meta.SE

Comment: @user8001250 As to the -13 downvotes your asking if manipulation of the reputation system is a good idea.  You should already know that cheating is a bad idea.  Basic human instinct.

Answer (score 10):

First, you should **never** go and vote (up **or** down) all of anyone's posts, for **any** reason. This includes knowing them, friendship, or because they gave a great answer to your question. NEVER. Vote the post, not the person.

Second, there are [safeguards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) that detect a lot of votes for the same person's posts in quick succession and remove them. Again, this works for both up and down. Don't ask what "a lot" or "quick" are in numbers; that's not public knowledge and you don't need to know.

Third, if a person repeatedly voted this way, I would expect they would receive a note from a [moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) telling them not to do it. People who ignore moderators notes may end up suspended (which is different from being [banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)) and while suspended their rep will be reduced to 1. If a person kept breaking the rules over and over, the suspensions would get longer and longer. It would be best not to experiment enough to find out precisely how that process unfolds.

Fourth, you wouldn't get 1000 rep even if the safeguards didn't remove the votes, because the [rep cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) limits you to 200 rep a day.

Fifth, much of what you're asking is in [the help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help). Reading it should reassure you. I added quite a few specific links above.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. but why i'm getting a lot of down vote here? :| If even it's duplicate topic, why got -13 down vote ! I'm banned from stack exchange! just for this question!

Comment: you were downvoted for asking something that is very well covered in the help centre, full of misconceptions (such as getting 1000 rep in a day) and suggested that voting for all of someone's posts is ok if you know them or are friends. Some of that may have been writing errors, but a post that is hard to read, contains misconceptions, and shows no research effort will be downvoted. Asking questions is a good way to learn but not the only way.

Comment: “I'm banned from stack exchange! just for this question!” - You were not banned, you simply have a extremely high rate limit for asking questions, which was from asking **several** uninformed questions in the past.  Improve your existing questions, and in 6 months, you will be given the chance to ask another question.

Comment: @Ramhound suspended six months for asking LQQs? Gasp! It's a bit OTT.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Under the impression the user is question “banned” not actually suspended. Question “bans” are more like 6 month rate limits per clarification provided by SE developers in the past

Comment: @Ramhound banned, and suspended are pretty synonymous. Still...six months. How does someone improve an off-topic question without rewriting it completely? Can banned users edit their questions and change nearly everything?

Comment: If a user is suspended then they cannot ask questions nor submit answers, if they are question "banned", then they have an extremely high rate limit, suspended users cannot make any changes to their content.  Users with an extremely high rate limit can always improve their content.  The two words are NOT synonymous with one another.